Singing: getting into the headspace of a complete beginner
In my lifetime, I've never struggled with pitch or rhythm perception. I've always had the ability to easily and accurately identify and reproduce melodies with my voice, even complex ones. So now, when I'm in a situation where I'm expected to coach people who cannot reproduce one single note correctly (while hearing it being played in real-time) without me explicitly telling them to adjust their pitch and in which direction the adjustment should be made, I'm at a complete loss when it comes to helping them improve.
This question is all about getting into the headspace of a complete novice at singing, and especially what I as someone helping out would benefit from knowing. Therefore, I'm mainly looking for accounts of people who have direct experience with being at an absolute beginner level with regards to singing. Specifically:

What is it like to be a complete beginner at singing? I just cannot for the life of me imagine what it's like not being able to reproduce a given note that is within my singing range. Is it a problem with voice control (i.e. you can hear that you're off, but you don't quite know how to control your vocal cords), or is it difficult to even hear that something is amiss tonewise?
If you were a complete beginner at singing who struggled to hit the right note, but you can now hit the right note without problems: what did you do in order to improve? Were there any specific pitch exercises you did, or was it a simple matter of just singing more than before?

Edit: this is part of a bigger question where a major goal is to figure out the best course of action in the following situation: Leading a choir where singers are at different skill levels.

I’m voting to close this question because there are too many questions here, some of which are already addressed on the site and some of which are “opinion-based”.

Interesting questions, but too many all at once. Split them up, and you're in with a chance!

As someone who started learning to sing at age 19, and couldn’t even match pitches before that, I can probably answer all of these pretty well at least from my experience. But I agree this should be several separate questions, not one big question.

@Aaron Noted, although I've struggled to find these answers myself on the site (I've been on the site for years, and still never got the hang of how to search it effectively). Do you have some links to relevant questions on this site that I could look at?

@Tim Noted, thanks for the feedback. Would you suggest I split all of them up into separate ones, or that I take some of them together (as I feel like some of these questions are very closely related, for instance 1 and 2 are basically asking for personal accounts).

If you remove everything except 1 and 2 I think I can answer those here. What you remove could be used to ask separate questions. 4 is definitely a topic all on its own. I think 3 and 5 are the same thing asked two different ways.

Ok thanks, will do! Is it better to leave this question up and let it get closed, or should I edit it directly?

Edit this question to be the first of the questions you want to ask

"I'm in a situation where I'm expected to coach people [...] without me explicitly telling them to adjust their pitch". Can you contextualize the "without" part? Why (or what) can't you tell them? Coaching is fundamentally a specific (yet somehow vague) aspect of teaching. It depends on many aspects, including if you're dealing with individuals or a group (a chorus?) and their age/experiences. Also, while knowing about personal experiences of people who struggled with these aspects may be helpful, there's a chance you'll only get a partial perspective that just coincidentally worked for them.

Here are a few relevant posts: How to learn to carry a tune, i.e. stay in some key or other; How to develop a musical ear when even singing poses great difficulty?; I want to learn how to sing. Where do I start?.

@musicamante this may be a matter of me being bad at expressing what I mean, but what I'm trying to describe is the following scenario:
I play a note, and ask them to sing the same note,
They sing a note, which is off.
They can't find the correct note without me explicitly guiding them there with direct instructions ("higher"/"lower").

@Aaron thanks for the suggestions, I will read them to see whether they answer my questions or whether I should edit mine further.

@Scounged It's relatively common to have difficulties in teaching when one had a somehow instinctive approach at a field (it's one of the reasons for which some wonderful musicians are also terrible teachers, at least for some of their students). The "how" depends on their age/level, if you're addressing a single/a section/a group, the purpose and the available time. Yet, there's absolutely nothing wrong in "guiding" someone in refining the pitch: it happens even at higher musical levels (eg: a conductor may tell an orchestra musician to fix their tuning in a specific part of the piece).

@Scounged If you're approaching an individual, it's theoretically simpler, as you can directly help them with simple exercises that allow them to understand how to control their pitch. Yet, being in a group also consisting of people being able to do so also helps: consider that, unless some neural/psychological limitations are in effect, anybody is able to control their vocal pitch, they just are not used to it; it's just about practising it correctly. Acoustic imitation is always helpful: for instance, sing "their" same note and "swing" it to the correct one asking them to "follow" you.

@Scounged Using elementary intervals is also helpful, starting with very large ones (their lower/higher notes), then going on with tunes they're familiar with. Physical association is also relevant, as associating the body to the pitch is extremely helpful in understanding/coordinating pitch control: for instance, have their hand in front of them and move it up/down while changing pitch, so they can understand more "physically" how they actually do that. Have a look at didactic methods such as Dalcroze or Kodaly, as they both associate body and music (with the latter more focused on voice).

@musicamante thanks for the advice, it gives me some direction on how my situation could be managed. As I specify in another question, this entire situation stems from me leading a choir with members of vastly different singing levels, and I'm struggling a lot to figure out how to conduct the sessions in a way so that they're productive for everyone there.

@Scounged Ok, then I suggest you to edit again your post and clarify that aspect. Even though we generally don't accept broad "how to" questions, this may still be an acceptable post if put in good form: personal experiences about struggling with tuning are fundamentally an extra (relevant, but, as said, partial and therefore secondary), mostly because they usually come from very personal paths that rarely work for anybody (and, especially, for a group). Unless you have the opportunity to work individually, you have to "coach" for a group, which makes the approach slightly different.

OP mentions several times the skill of reproducing a single note.  I think for many beginners this is more difficult than roughly singing back a short snatch of scale or familiar melody (on the level of “Twinkle twinkle little star / how I wonder what you are”).  Most early voice pedagogy I’ve seen starts with simple melodies first, for completely untrained beginners, and then moves onto single note/interval exercises  only after that.

@PLL This is definitely something that I have NOT considered at all. I've always assumed that it's easier to sing a single note, because then it's just one note you have to focus on. But it just goes to show how little I know about early voice pedagogy.

I recommend teaching and drilling solfege. Having the language to talk about different pitches can go miles. Just take care not to leave anyone behind - even the simplest exercises will reinforce good habits.

From my personal experience:

I think it's reasonable to require/expect that even the most naive beginner can tell when a pitch is high versus low, given sufficient separation. Someone who can't tell the difference between a higher pitch and a lower pitch (e.g., more than an octave apart) might be "tone deaf" and might not be able to learn to sing. I've never known anyone like this.
You can't assume everyone knows how to tell when a two notes are at the same pitch and in tune. I had to be taught this. I was taught, through demonstration, what a beat frequency is and how the beating speeds up as one note becomes less in tune with another note. This was an eye-opening revelation for me.
Even after learning to hear beat frequencies, it took practice to tell, between two fairly close pitches, which was the higher one. This meant when I was learning to match pitches I had to often try going up and down to see which direction made me closer to the target pitch.
Singing unisons with a steady pitch is easier than singing the same pitch but in a different octave. Singing a desired interval away from a steady pitch is a whole different level.

With daily practice, here are my personal time frames for gaining the following abilities:

Matching a pitch fairly closely in unison given 1-5 seconds to find it: days to weeks.
Singing along in unison with another singer and having barely acceptable intonation: weeks to months.
Singing unaccompanied with an initial reference pitch a scale that is clearly major (or minor) but not arriving in tune after going up or down an octave: a few months.
Singing melodic intervals back right after hearing them: months to years, depending on context.
Singing an octave above a steady reference pitch: weeks to months; a fifth: months; a third: more than a year I think; other intervals: ummm... I think I could do this (30 years after starting to sing).
Sight-singing a passage after being given a starting reference pitch: at least 3-5 years with professional training and practice.


If you were a complete beginner at singing who struggled to hit the right note, but you can now hit the right note without problems: what did you do in order to improve? Were there any specific pitch exercises you did, or was it a simple matter of just singing more than before?

At first I sat at the piano every day and practiced matching pitches and listening for beat frequencies. I also drove every day for school or work for a couple decades and usually sang along to every song on the radio that was in my range, and a few that weren't. I recently completed a 2-year aural skills program at a US university and before starting that I could sing major and minor scales pretty well and audiate and sing melodies that I had heard many, many times. I learned to audiate and then sing arbitrary intervals by making a chart of melodies I already know well that start with or feature the interval (e.g., the Star Wars theme starts with an ascending perfect fifth).
My experience with singing is that it's essentially like learning to play an instrument (I've learned at least competence on several instruments as an adult). You should be able to make notes in an hour or two, play/sing your first scale in a week or two, but expect it to take 2-5 years before you can really perform music that is not beginner etudes. Even longer to be semi-pro. This is with daily practice and goes fastest with a competent private teacher.

Lots of excellent points, but one minor note on the first point: I’d only expect beginners to reliably distinguish higher/lower pitches within the same voice/instrument.  Comparing pitches between different voices (especially including one’s own) is a bit more of a learned skill, in part because of the (important and useful) tendency to equate notes at the octave.  As in my comment on the question, I think singing back a single heard note is harder for many beginners than singing back a short stretch of melody.

The short answer would be:

You don't notice.
Acquire enough aural experience to start noticing.

The long answer is that our perception is strongly determined by our (unconscious) goals, expectations and previous experience.  Do you remember the famous experiment with basketball players and a gorilla?  (If not, you can search "the invisible gorilla" or "selective attention".)  If something is too foreign or does not make sense or simply isn't relevant or interesting our brain ignores it.  (Well, maybe it doesn't ignore it but it's not available consciously.)  However absurd it may seem to a trained musician, a person can produce sounds and be oblivious to their pitch/timbre/rhythm/other characteristics simply because it never occured to them that it's something worth their attention, or that it's even a thing.
I became a musician without being particularly gifted or talented at music.  When I was seven I could not identify the first interval of Chopin's e minor prelude.  It starts with an octave but as a child I sang a perfect fifth and couldn't be happier.  Only months later there came a vague doubt that something was amiss.  I tried both variants at the piano and still couldn't figure it out.  It felt like it could be both and there was no way to tell them apart.  In the end, I had to ask an adult.
At around the same age, I had trouble with the repeated figure in Mozart's 40th symphony (at measures 16-19), namely how many times to play it.  I would play the melody but when repeats came I would get lost.  Felt like being overwhelmed, and after the first one, they all sounded the same.
It's possible the above examples are explained by the limitations of a child's cognitive abilities (as in Piaget's theory) but it definitely does not apply equally to all children, otherwise we wouldn't get Mozart and other child prodigies.  I think the useful insight from these anecdotes could be the feeling of being overwhelmed in a situation where you have no prior experience to draw upon.  Until you acquire some familiarity, you remain helpless, as probably some of your students.
Moving on to teenage years, singing harmonies with friends, I would get mad at them (friends, that is) for being out of tune until one day I realized it was me who was the culprit.  I found this out purely by accident;  I definitely did not hear my voice the way it actually sounded, there was no aural feedback, I simply believed that my pitch had to be correct and someone else was at fault.
Years later I tried singing backing vocals in a band (with very limited success), this time though a mic and PA and again I found out that what I heard from the speakers didn't match what I imagined in my head.  I'm not talking about timbre which is a surprise for everyone (as it was for me of course), the notes were off.  It felt like someone else's voice.
To sum it all up, to get someone to sing well you must direct their attention to the result of their vocalizations and it is not a trivial process, it does not come naturally to everyone.  Perhaps some children develop interest in their voice so early that for them observing sound is a natural process.  For others, this must be done intentionally.  Recording seems to be a quick method to achieve that.
